# Unable to access date value in an object

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I'm using `Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client`

When I print  `$instance['LaunchTime']` I get:

```
Aws\Api\DateTimeResult Object
(
    [date] => 2020-03-03 17:13:13
    [timezone_type] => 2
    [timezone] => Z
)
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to access `date` value.

```
$dt = $instance['LaunchTime'];

print($dt->date); //does not work
print($dt['date']); //does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to this way

```
$dt = $instance['LaunchTime'];
print($dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$instance['LaunchTime']` is an instance of `Aws\Api\DateTimeResult`, which issimilar to a [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, so try using that.

Answer (score 0):

`Class DateTimeResult` implements `DateTimeInterface`, so it works just the same as the PHP [DateTime Class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). So you'd use it like this:

```
print($dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```